# Ionic click event not working in ion-list

Tags: ionic2

I'm currently developing a ionic 2 application,using a list with an ion-avatar. The thing is I created this in my `home.html` page but I want to make the list items clickable, so that when I click on any item, it will redirect to the details page and display the details of that item in the list.

My code is shown below:

[image: htmlpage.html]

[image: The output]

I tried to use the `onclick` event with a function but I can't figure out how to get the functionality working

Comment: can you show your @component code? your list items are ok

Comment: Ok you mean the home.ts file code

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      
       
  }

      
  }

Comment: @AliSattar  you are make the click on the first item and i can't see the `details` object you are sending to the js

Comment: where is the code of your openPage function?

Comment: Yes this is what i want to ask about: is the click event is correct to solve this problem?

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I solved by using functions with using (click) event.